# How does one apply MVC design to audio development with CoreAudio and Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, model-view-controller

I am trying to get into audio development a little bit, but my question have to do with program design.

Apple and Cocoa pushes developers to use MVC for designing applications, and that makes sense when developing GUI based applications.

I want to stick with MVC in developing audio parts of my application, but there doesn't seem to be much information out there on design strategy for audio applications. I am also cannot decide on the best way parts of an audio application can fit into MVC.  For example, is the Audio Interface communication [IO] part of the model or part of the view?

I am just curious, if anyone has tips for designing audio applications.

Comment: Are you talking about voice-controlled apps or something that manipulates existing audio files?

Comment: Something that manipulates existing audio files or generates real-time audio like a software synthesizer.

Comment: In that case: definitely the model layer. Because audio input (files of stream) in your case is the data source on which your domain logic acts. *(I am referring to [rich model implementation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html): the MVC's model layer in this link is all 3 concentric circles together, where with "domain model" was meant concept described in [this book](http://books.google.lv/books/?id=hHBf4YxMnWMC&redir_esc=y))*